# Convert linestringz to linestringm using alter column?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, linestring

I am attempting to import linestring data with or without m values, then test whether the data has m values, then add m values to the geometry if they are missing.  So far, I have working tests for the m values, and I can create the new geometry with m values included when using a select statement.  However, I am trying to use this test in an alter table/alter column statement, which doesn't allow subqueries.  I needed the subquery that I am using in order to convert a linestringz to a linestringm.  I thought there would be a postgis function to swap coordinates between z and m, like st_force3dm(geom, st_z(geom)), which obviously doesn't work because st_z requires a point.  **Is there a way to swap a linestringz to linestringm using the z values as the new m values, and within an alter table statement?**

This is the code I have so far.  It tests whether m values exists, whether they are all 0, whether z values exist and whether they are all 0.  If it finds m values that are not all 0, it returns the original geometry.  If it finds no z or m values, or z and m values are all 0, it uses the geometry length to create m values.  If it finds z values that are not all 0, it creates a linestringm using the z values as the m values.  This last part doesn't work in an alter table statement because I have used a subquery to assign the z values to m values.  I'm open to suggestions about better ways to achieve this task.

Doesn't work due to subquery in alter table:

```
alter table mt_altis_statewide_routes alter column geom type geometry(multilinestringm,4326) using 
    case when ((st_m(st_startpoint(geom)) = 0 and st_m(st_endpoint(geom)) = 0) or st_m(st_startpoint(geom)) is null) 
        and ((st_z(st_startpoint(geom)) = 0 and st_z(st_endpoint(geom)) = 0) or st_z(st_endpoint(geom)) is null) 
        then st_addmeasure(geom,0,length_miles(geom)) 
    when ((st_m(st_startpoint(geom)) = 0 and st_m(st_endpoint(geom)) = 0) or st_m(st_startpoint(geom)) is null) 
        and (st_z(st_startpoint(geom)) != 0 or st_z(st_endpoint(geom)) != 0) and st_z(st_startpoint(geom)) is not null 
        then (select st_setsrid(st_makeline(st_makepointm(st_x(geom),st_y(geom),st_z(geom)) order by st_z(geom)),4326) from (select (st_dumppoints(geom)).geom) as f) 
    when ((st_z(st_startpoint(geom)) = 0 and st_z(st_endpoint(geom)) = 0) or st_z(st_startpoint(geom)) is null) 
        and (st_m(st_startpoint(geom)) != 0 or st_m(st_endpoint(geom)) != 0) and st_m(st_startpoint(geom)) is not null 
        then geom end;
```

Works as select statement:

```
select 
    case when ((st_m(st_startpoint(geom)) = 0 and st_m(st_endpoint(geom)) = 0) or st_m(st_startpoint(geom)) is null) 
        and ((st_z(st_startpoint(geom)) = 0 and st_z(st_endpoint(geom)) = 0) or st_z(st_endpoint(geom)) is null) 
        then st_addmeasure(geom,0,length_miles(geom)) 
    when ((st_m(st_startpoint(geom)) = 0 and st_m(st_endpoint(geom)) = 0) or st_m(st_startpoint(geom)) is null) 
        and (st_z(st_startpoint(geom)) != 0 or st_z(st_endpoint(geom)) != 0) and st_z(st_startpoint(geom)) is not null 
        then (select st_setsrid(st_makeline(st_makepointm(st_x(geom),st_y(geom),st_z(geom)) order by st_z(geom)),4326) from (select (st_dumppoints(geom)).geom) as f) 
    when ((st_z(st_startpoint(geom)) = 0 and st_z(st_endpoint(geom)) = 0) or st_z(st_startpoint(geom)) is null) 
        and (st_m(st_startpoint(geom)) != 0 or st_m(st_endpoint(geom)) != 0) and st_m(st_startpoint(geom)) is not null 
        then geom end geom 
from mt_state_maintained_routes msmr ;
```

Comment: Just put your logic into a function and call that. Make sure it returns the full type definition, e.g. `RETURNS GEOMETRY(MULTILINESTRINGM, 4326)`.

Comment: I suppose that the original geometry type is multilinestringZM because you need to analyze the coordinates, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by first converting my geometry to 4D, which keeps the Z coordinates intact and provides the coordinate dimension required for the next step.  I discovered that there is a postgis function to swap  ordinates (**[St_SwapOrdinates](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SwapOrdinates.html)**).  Chaining these together allowed me to swap m and z values for the lines, and it works in an alter table statement without the need for a custom function.

```
alter table mt_altis_statewide_routes alter column geom type geometry(multilinestringm,4326) using 
    case when ((st_m(st_startpoint(geom)) = 0 and st_m(st_endpoint(geom)) = 0) or st_m(st_startpoint(geom)) is null) 
        and ((st_z(st_startpoint(geom)) = 0 and st_z(st_endpoint(geom)) = 0) or st_z(st_endpoint(geom)) is null) 
        then st_addmeasure(geom,0,length_miles(geom)) 
    when ((st_m(st_startpoint(geom)) = 0 and st_m(st_endpoint(geom)) = 0) or st_m(st_startpoint(geom)) is null) 
        and (st_z(st_startpoint(geom)) != 0 or st_z(st_endpoint(geom)) != 0) and st_z(st_startpoint(geom)) is not null 
        then st_force3dm(st_swapordinates(st_force4d(geom),'zm')) 
    when ((st_z(st_startpoint(geom)) = 0 and st_z(st_endpoint(geom)) = 0) or st_z(st_startpoint(geom)) is null) 
        and (st_m(st_startpoint(geom)) != 0 or st_m(st_endpoint(geom)) != 0) and st_m(st_startpoint(geom)) is not null 
        then geom end;
```

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comments it would be necessary put your conversion code in a function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION make_multilinestringm(geometry) RETURNS geometry(multilinestringm,4326) AS $$
DECLARE 
    geom geometry;  
BEGIN
    geom = $1;
   case  
       when (( st_m(st_startpoint(geom)) = 0 and st_m(st_endpoint(geom)) = 0) or st_m(st_startpoint(geom)) is null) 
            and ((st_z(st_startpoint(geom)) = 0 and st_z(st_endpoint(geom)) = 0) or st_z(st_endpoint(geom)) is null) 
            then return st_addmeasure(geom,0,length_miles(geom));        
       when ((st_m(st_startpoint(geom)) = 0 and st_m(st_endpoint(geom)) = 0) or st_m(st_startpoint(geom)) is null) 
            and (st_z(st_startpoint(geom)) != 0 or st_z(st_endpoint(geom)) != 0) and st_z(st_startpoint(geom)) is not null 
            then return (select st_setsrid(st_makeline(st_makepointm(st_x(geom),st_y(geom),st_z(geom)) order by st_z(geom)),4326) from (select (st_dumppoints(geom)).geom) as f); 
       when ((st_z(st_startpoint(geom)) = 0 and st_z(st_endpoint(geom)) = 0) or st_z(st_startpoint(geom)) is null) 
            and (st_m(st_startpoint(geom)) != 0 or st_m(st_endpoint(geom)) != 0) and st_m(st_startpoint(geom)) is not null 
            then return geom; 
    end case;    
END;
$$
STRICT
LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

and then execute alter sentence using it

```
alter table mt_altis_statewide_routes alter column geom type geometry(multilinestringm,4326) using make_multilinestringm(geom);
```